# what to use for web application that finds out information about windows/mac

Tags: java, spring-boot, web-applications, applet

I am a java beginner, looking for pointers to go about writing a web application that would

1. get downloaded from a internal server,
2. reads the system information like, OS, antivirus status - on Mac / Windows
3. generates a report for the user to view

from what i understand this could be done using applets. I learnt that applets are not supported any longer. so any pointers in the right direction would be very helpful

Comment: Web apps can get the OS, the OS version, and some limited information about the browser. That's about it. For anything else you'll need to write a desktop application.

Comment: got it thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

First thing first. You need to understand difference in between Web Application and Desktop application.

You should look for desktop application, which can read data from installed computer and send data using API and API will save that data in some DB and then you can generate reports from it.

In JAVA you can create a executable JAR to do some job on user's computer.

Comment: that changed my perspective, thanks a lot. I am assuming i need to come up with a java application, which does the necessary work, make it a jar. this would be then downloaded by the user from the internal site.